# CNN in keras overfitting even after dropout and batch normalization

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train my model by [finetuning](https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface#finetuning) a pretrained [model](https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface)(vggface). My model has 12 classes with 1774 training images and 313 validation images, each class having around 150 images.
My model was overfitting so I added dropout and FC layers with batch normalization to see how it goes. But still, the model overfits:

```
train_data_path = 'dataset_cfps/train'
validation_data_path = 'dataset_cfps/validation'

#Parametres
img_width, img_height = 224, 224

vggface = VGGFace(model='resnet50', include_top=False, input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))

last_layer = vggface.get_layer('avg_pool').output
x = Flatten(name='flatten')(last_layer)
xx = Dense(1024, activation = 'softmax')(x)
x2 = Dropout(0.5)(xx)
y = Dense(1024, activation = 'softmax')(x2)
yy = BatchNormalization()(y)
y1 = Dropout(0.5)(yy)
x3 = Dense(12, activation='softmax', name='classifier')(y1)

custom_vgg_model = Model(vggface.input, x3)


# Create the model
model = models.Sequential()

# Add the convolutional base model
model.add(custom_vgg_model)

model.summary()
model = load_model('facenet_resnet_lr3_SGD_relu_1024.h5')

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1./255,
      rotation_range=20,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      fill_mode='nearest')


validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# Change the batchsize according to your system RAM
train_batchsize = 32
val_batchsize = 32

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_path,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=train_batchsize,
        class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_data_path,
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=val_batchsize,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=True)

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-3),
              metrics=['acc'])
# Train the model
history = model.fit_generator(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples/train_generator.batch_size ,
      epochs=100,
      validation_data=validation_generator,
      validation_steps=validation_generator.samples/validation_generator.batch_size,
      verbose=1)

# Save the model
model.save('facenet_resnet_lr3_SGD_relu_1024_1.h5')
```

Here are the epochs:

```
 (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
model_5 (Model)              (None, 12)                26725324  
=================================================================
Total params: 26,725,324
Trainable params: 26,670,156
Non-trainable params: 55,168
_________________________________________________________________
Found 1774 images belonging to 12 classes.
Found 313 images belonging to 12 classes.
.
.
.
Epoch 70/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 880ms/step - loss: 0.5433 - acc: 0.8987 - val_loss: 0.8271 - val_acc: 0.7796
Epoch 71/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 880ms/step - loss: 0.5353 - acc: 0.9145 - val_loss: 0.7954 - val_acc: 0.7508
Epoch 72/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 880ms/step - loss: 0.5353 - acc: 0.8955 - val_loss: 0.8690 - val_acc: 0.7348
Epoch 73/100

56/55 [==============================] - 49s 880ms/step - loss: 0.5310 - acc: 0.9037 - val_loss: 0.8673 - val_acc: 0.7476
Epoch 74/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 880ms/step - loss: 0.5189 - acc: 0.8943 - val_loss: 0.8701 - val_acc: 0.7380
Epoch 75/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 880ms/step - loss: 0.5333 - acc: 0.8952 - val_loss: 0.9399 - val_acc: 0.7188
Epoch 76/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 879ms/step - loss: 0.5106 - acc: 0.9043 - val_loss: 0.8107 - val_acc: 0.7700
Epoch 77/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 880ms/step - loss: 0.5108 - acc: 0.9064 - val_loss: 0.9624 - val_acc: 0.6869
Epoch 78/100

56/55 [==============================] - 49s 880ms/step - loss: 0.5214 - acc: 0.8994 - val_loss: 0.9602 - val_acc: 0.6933
Epoch 79/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 880ms/step - loss: 0.5246 - acc: 0.9009 - val_loss: 0.8379 - val_acc: 0.7572
Epoch 80/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 879ms/step - loss: 0.4859 - acc: 0.9082 - val_loss: 0.7856 - val_acc: 0.7796
Epoch 81/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 881ms/step - loss: 0.5005 - acc: 0.9175 - val_loss: 0.7609 - val_acc: 0.7827
Epoch 82/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 880ms/step - loss: 0.4690 - acc: 0.9294 - val_loss: 0.7671 - val_acc: 0.7636
Epoch 83/100

56/55 [==============================] - 49s 879ms/step - loss: 0.4897 - acc: 0.9146 - val_loss: 0.7902 - val_acc: 0.7636
Epoch 84/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 879ms/step - loss: 0.4604 - acc: 0.9291 - val_loss: 0.7603 - val_acc: 0.7636
Epoch 85/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 881ms/step - loss: 0.4750 - acc: 0.9220 - val_loss: 0.7325 - val_acc: 0.7668
Epoch 86/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 879ms/step - loss: 0.4524 - acc: 0.9266 - val_loss: 0.7782 - val_acc: 0.7636
Epoch 87/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 880ms/step - loss: 0.4643 - acc: 0.9172 - val_loss: 0.9892 - val_acc: 0.6901
Epoch 88/100

56/55 [==============================] - 49s 881ms/step - loss: 0.4718 - acc: 0.9177 - val_loss: 0.8269 - val_acc: 0.7380
Epoch 89/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 879ms/step - loss: 0.4646 - acc: 0.9290 - val_loss: 0.7846 - val_acc: 0.7604
Epoch 90/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 879ms/step - loss: 0.4433 - acc: 0.9341 - val_loss: 0.7693 - val_acc: 0.7764
Epoch 91/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 877ms/step - loss: 0.4706 - acc: 0.9196 - val_loss: 0.8200 - val_acc: 0.7604
Epoch 92/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 880ms/step - loss: 0.4572 - acc: 0.9184 - val_loss: 0.9220 - val_acc: 0.7220
Epoch 93/100

56/55 [==============================] - 49s 880ms/step - loss: 0.4479 - acc: 0.9175 - val_loss: 0.8781 - val_acc: 0.7348
Epoch 94/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 879ms/step - loss: 0.4793 - acc: 0.9100 - val_loss: 0.8035 - val_acc: 0.7572
Epoch 95/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 879ms/step - loss: 0.4329 - acc: 0.9279 - val_loss: 0.7750 - val_acc: 0.7796
Epoch 96/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 879ms/step - loss: 0.4361 - acc: 0.9212 - val_loss: 0.8124 - val_acc: 0.7508
Epoch 97/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 880ms/step - loss: 0.4371 - acc: 0.9202 - val_loss: 0.9806 - val_acc: 0.7029
Epoch 98/100

56/55 [==============================] - 49s 880ms/step - loss: 0.4298 - acc: 0.9149 - val_loss: 0.8637 - val_acc: 0.7380
Epoch 99/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 880ms/step - loss: 0.4370 - acc: 0.9255 - val_loss: 0.8349 - val_acc: 0.7604
Epoch 100/100
56/55 [==============================] - 49s 880ms/step - loss: 0.4407 - acc: 0.9205 - val_loss: 0.8477 - val_acc: 0.7508
```

Comment: Use ReLu as an activation function on hidden layers. Or even better, Leaky ReLu.

Answer (score 0):

CNN deep networks need a huge data for training. You have a little dataset and the model is unable to generalize from this small dataset. You have two options

1. reduce the network size
2. increase the number of dataset

#### EDIT after comments on answer:

The model has some issues. You wouldn't use softmax for hidden layers.
If you want to overcome the over-fitting issue you would freeze the trained layers and train only new added layers. If the model still overfits, you may remove some of layers you have added or lower their number of units.

Comment: How could I reduce the network size from a pretrained model?

Comment: you will have to frezze the pretrained resnet layers so that you only learn on the bottom layers

`for layer in model.layers[:how_many_layers_want_to_freeze]:
    layer.trainable = False`

and don't use softmax as activation for Dense layers go for relu activation which will help you avoid saturation

Comment: actually using relu was giving me higher losses, so that's why I was using softmax. I want to freeze till the last conv layer. How can i do that? @thefifthjack005